# Rails how to sort with link by count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Rails 4. I got an output in output:

```
  <% @places.each do |place| %>
  <tr>
    <td>
    All subscriptions: <%= Subscription.where(place_id: place.id).count %> 
    Males: <%= Subscription.where(user_gender: 'male', place_id: place.id).count %> 
    Females: <%= Subscription.where(user_gender: 'female', place_id: place.id).count %>
    </td>
    <td><p><%= image_tag place.place_photo(:small) %></td>
    <td><%= place.title %></td>
    <td><%= place.place_type.title %></td>
    <td><%= place.content %></td>
    <td><%= place.address %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

And i want to sort by subscriptions.count how can i make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you do 2 things. First add counter caches on your Subscription model.

Add columns in your subscriptions table using a migration

```
add_column :subscriptions, :places_count, :integer, :default => 0
add_column :subscriptions, :male_places_count, :integer, :default => 0
add_column :subscriptions, :female_places_count, :integer, :default => 0
```

Modify your Place and Subscription models to update theses counts

```
class Place
  def update_subscription_counters
    subscription.update_counters
  end
  after_create :update_subscription_counters
  after_destroy :update_subscription_counters
end

class Subscription
  def update_counters
    self.places_count = places.count
    self.male_places_count = places.male.count
    self.female_places_count = places.female.count
    self.save
  end
end
```

These counts will all then be updated when you create/destroy a place, and when you enumerate your places, you wont end up with any unnecessary count queries.

Second, you can then use these to order your places.

```
class SubscriptionsController
  def show
    subscription = Subscription.find(params[:id])
    @places = subscription.places.includes(:subscription).order(:places_count)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to sort @places by subscriptoin count:

`@places.joins(:subscriptions).group("places.id").select("places.*, count(*) as subscriptions_count").order("subscriptions_count DESC").each do`

Note: You should do these mysql queries in your controller or a model, not in your view.

You can output the subscription count inside your each simply by using `<%= place.subscription_count %>` because it is included via the select()